# "Fingerprint hardware not available" after TWRP restore

Tags: permissions, fingerprint

A couple months ago I had to get a replacement for my Nexus 6P, so I did a full TWRP backup, copied it onto the new phone, and did a restore (note that I had to rename the backup folder so that TWRP would recognize it). Since then various things haven't quite been working correctly, but one of the most annoying things is the fingerprint reader.

Whenever I turn on the screen, a red message appears at the bottom of the lock screen that says "Fingerprint hardware not available". In addition, when I go to Settings > Lock screen > Fingerprint, the fingerprints I had set up are listed (and I can rename them), but when I try to delete one, nothing happens. Additionally, when I tap "Add fingerprint", it goes to the screen to set up a new fingerprint but then a message immediately pops up that says "Fingerprint enrollment didn't work. Try again or use a different finger." Also, when I open the fingerprint screen (even while it's still prompting me for my PIN), I get this:

```
05-28 21:33:20.343  3787  3787 V fingerprintd: authenticate(sid=0, gid=0)
05-28 21:33:20.352  3787  6214 E fpc_tac : fpc_tac_send_get_uint32_cmd failed with retval: -3
05-28 21:33:20.352  3787  6214 E fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_identify failed -5
05-28 21:33:20.352  3787  6214 D fingerprintd: onError(1)
```

repeated endlessly in `adb logcat`.

Deleting a fingerprint results (AFAICT) in this:

```
05-28 21:37:15.506 22939 22939 V FingerprintSettings: Removing fpId=983097043
05-28 21:37:15.506  4852  6197 D AudioService: Stream muted, skip playback
05-28 21:37:15.508  3787  3787 V fingerprintd: remove(fid=983097043, gid=0)
05-28 21:37:15.513  3787  3787 E fpc_tac : fpc_tac_send_get_uint32_cmd failed with retval: -3
05-28 21:37:15.515  3787  3787 E fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_remove failed -5
05-28 21:37:15.515  4852  4852 W FingerprintService: startRemove with id = 983097043 failed, result=-1
05-28 21:37:15.526  3787  3787 V fingerprintd: authenticate(sid=0, gid=0)
05-28 21:37:15.527  3787  3787 V fingerprintd: stopAuthentication()
05-28 21:37:15.529  3787  6214 E fpc_tac : fpc_tac_send_get_uint32_cmd failed with retval: -3
05-28 21:37:15.529  3787  6214 E fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_identify failed -5
05-28 21:37:15.529  3787  6214 D fingerprintd: onError(1)
```

and from there it repeats endlessly again.

There's nothing else in `adb logcat` when I tap "Add fingerprint" besides a log entry about the Activity being started.

Any ideas? I've searched the web extensively and even poked around in the source, all with no luck.

I'm on CyanogenMod 13.0-20160522-NIGHTLY-angler, but this is definitely unrelated to the fact that it's a nightly.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue after TWRP restoring a full backup of cm-13.0-20160913-NIGHTLY-angler on a new device. I updated it to 13.0-20161106-NIGHTLY yesterday. The update was successful, but the fingerprint errors still persist. Were you able to find a solution? I was trying to find the location where Android stores the fingerprint data and asked the question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161780/where-does-android-store-fingerprint-data

Comment: See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173785/65316): if you remove the right files, you'll be able to interact with the fingerprint scanner again.