# Where does Android store fingerprint data?

Tags: root-access, twrp, system, nexus-6p, fingerprint

I am looking for the files that correspond to the recorded fingerprints on my Nexus 6P and a way to "reset" the fingerprint system. Something similar to how Android stores lock screen settings (pattern etc.) under `/data/system/locksettings.db*`, and you can remove the lock screen by deleting these files (if you have root access).

The reason I am asking is because after a TWRP restore on a new Nexus 6P, my fingerprint hardware is not working anymore. The error message is **Fingerprint hardware not available**. Also see this question: ["Fingerprint hardware not available" after TWRP restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146010/fingerprint-hardware-not-available-after-twrp-restore)

All five previously recorded fingerprints show up on the settings UI, but I am not able to delete them by clicking "Delete".

Answer (score 9):

try removing these files also

```
/data/system/users/0/fpdata/user.db
/data/system/users/0/settings_fingerprint.xml
```

Instead of removing files, appending the filenames with some random extension would be better. So, if anything goes wrong we can revert the changes. 
eg: `user.db` -> `user.db.xyz` or `xyx_user.db`

I faced the same error too and this worked for me.

Comment: That's one step closer! Thanks @lazykiller. Removing the files got rid of the "Fingerprint hardware not available" error message. However, when I try to set up new fingerprints in Settings now, I am getting this error "Enrollment was not completed". In logcat I'm seeing `fpc_tac_send_cmd failed with retval: -3`, `do_enroll failed -5`, and `onError(1)` from `fingerprintd`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me (after messing with the other files in /data/system)

Answer (score 1):

Secure location

Capturing and recognizing your fingerprint must happen in a secure part of the hardware known as a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE).

Hardware access must be limited to the TEE and protected by an SELinux policy.

**Fingerprint data must be secured within sensor hardware or trusted memory so that images of your fingerprint aren't accessible.**

Source: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6300638?hl=en

Click on *Fingerprint hardware security requirements* to get to the information, it's the last bullet point

Comment: That's useful information. Thank you. But then the real question is: My backed up and restored ROM shows the fingerprints on the UI. Where does the Android system get this information from and why does it still think 5 fingerprints are stored? Obviously the real fingerprint data is locked inside my old, bricked 6P. I just need a way to reset the fingerprints on my new phone.