# Can we get single time access to in-display fingerprint photos in android?

Tags: applications, security, fingerprint

I am trying to access the fingerprint photo access from the in-display fingerprint sensor for a specific use case. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Related: [Where does Android store fingerprint data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161780/44325)

Answer (score 1):

For privacy reasons fingerprints images can never be accessed by Android apps. The following text is about Google Nexus/Pixel phones, but as far as I know it also applies to phones of other manufacturer:

> Your fingerprint data is stored securely and never leaves your Pixel
> or Nexus phone. Your fingerprint data isn't shared with Google or any
> apps on your device. Apps are notified only whether your fingerprint
> was verified.

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6300638

The reader is only usable by Android itself for authentication.

As an app developer you can only ask Android to perform an authentication and in the end get the result (success/failure).